# What is a way to generate OTP 6-digit pin in C# .NET WCF? (without using Random())

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to generate an OTP 6-digit pin in my C# .NET Application. However, for security reasons, I heard that using the Random() package to perform this action might not be the most appropriate. Are there any other methods available?

Comment: 6 decimal digits?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You definitely want to use something in the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace if you want something more secure than `System.Random`.

Here's a handy implementation written by Eric Lippert in his fabulous [Fixing Random](https://ericlippert.com/2019/01/31/fixing-random-part-1/) series.

```
public static class BetterRandom
{
    private static readonly ThreadLocal<System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator> crng = new ThreadLocal<System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator>(System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator.Create);
    private static readonly ThreadLocal<byte[]> bytes = new ThreadLocal<byte[]>(() => new byte[sizeof(int)]);
    public static int NextInt()
    {
        crng.Value.GetBytes(bytes.Value);
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes.Value, 0) & int.MaxValue;
    }
    public static double NextDouble()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            long x = NextInt() & 0x001FFFFF;
            x <<= 31;
            x |= (long)NextInt();
            double n = x;
            const double d = 1L << 52;
            double q = n / d;
            if (q != 1.0)
                return q;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can easily create a OTP string:

```
string otp = (BetterRandom.NextInt() % 1000000).ToString("000000");
```

Comment: As I think Eric discusses in the linked series, just using modulus is likely to introduce bias. Probably not a large one since an int.MaxValue is so much larger, but potentially a real problem if someone uses the example for a pin with more digits.

Comment: @JonasH - Agreed. It's probably not super critical, but any small chink can be enough to get someone started in cracking the system.

Comment: @JonasH - The bias is quite small. It's averaging `4.49985323333333` over `10 000 000` repetitions when the average should be `4.5`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to generate a 6-digit OTP is to use a cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator (CSPRNG). A CSPRNG is a random number generator that is designed to be resistant to attackers trying to predict the numbers that will be generated.

One popular CSPRNG is the Microsoft Cryptographic Service Provider (CSP) Random Number Generator. To use this CSPRNG, you can call the `System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider.GetBytes` method, passing in the number of bytes you want to generate. This method will return an array of bytes, which you can then convert into a 6-digit string by taking the first 6 bytes and converting them to hexadecimal.

Another option is to use the `System.Random` class, but you should only do this if you are sure that the seed value you are using is truly random and cannot be predicted by an attacker.

Comment: `RandomNumberGenerator.Create()` is more portable.

Comment: "Pin" might imply "0-9". Regardless, just converting bytes to hexadecimal is probably not correct. You need to be careful when converting random values to something else, since it is easy to introduce bias. A safe, but potentially slow method is rejection sampling. I.e. take a byte, if it is less than 100, great! you got two pin digits, if it is larger, try again.

Comment: `new string(Enumerable.Range(1, 6).Select(i => $"{RandomNumberGenerator.GetInt32(0, 10)}"[0]).ToArray())`